# Remove from localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to do a basic todo list exercise here. I'm able to get todos from local storage and render them and i'm able to remove them from the screen but for some reason my deleteTodosFromStorage function doesnt work properly
everytime i reload the page i get the items that i deleted. i couldn't remove the local storage values.

Here is my html code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container" style ="margin-top:20px;">
                                     
        <div class="card row">
            <div class="card-header">Todo List</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                    <form id = "todo-form" name="form">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="todo" id = "todo" placeholder="Bir Todo Girin">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Todo Ekleyin</button>
                    </form>
                    
                    <hr>
                    
                    
                
             </div>
         
             <div class="card-body">
                    <hr>
                    <h5 class="card-title" id = "tasks-title">Todolar</h5>
                    <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="filter" id = "filter" placeholder="Bir Todo Arayın">
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <!-- <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
                            Todo 1
                            <a href = "#" class ="delete-item">
                                <i class = "fa fa-remove"></i>
                            </a>

                        </li>-->

                        
                    </ul>
                    <hr>  
                    <a id = "clear-todos" class="btn btn-dark" href="#">Tüm Taskları Temizleyin</a>               
                </div>
              </div>
        
    </div>


    
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="todo1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my JS code:

```
const list = document.querySelector(".list-group");
const todoInput = document.querySelector("#todo");
const cardBody = document.querySelectorAll(".card-body")[0];
const cardBody2 = document.querySelectorAll(".card-body")[1];


form.addEventListener("submit", addTodo);
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",loadTodosFromStorage);
cardBody2.addEventListener("click",deleteTodos);

function deleteTodos(e){

    if(e.target.className === "fa fa-remove"){
        e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        showAlert("success","Silme İşlmei Başarılı");
        deleteTodosFromStorage(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.textContent);

    }
}
function deleteTodosFromStorage(deletetodo){
    let todos = getTodosFromStorage();
    todos.forEach(function(todo,index){
        if(todo === deletetodo){
            todos.splice(index,1);          
        }
    });
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
}

function loadTodosFromStorage(){
    let todos = getTodosFromStorage();
    todos.forEach(function(todo){
        addListItem(todo);
    })
}
function addTodo(e){
    const value = todoInput.value.trim();
    if (value === ""){
        showAlert("danger", "Lütfen Bir Değer Giriniz");
    }
    else {
        addListItem(value);
        showAlert("success", "Todo Girişi Başarılı!");
        AddTodosToStorage(value);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
function getTodosFromStorage(){
    let todos;
    if(localStorage.getItem("todos")=== null){
        todos = [];
    }
    else{
        todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
    }
    return todos;
}
function AddTodosToStorage(value){
    let todos = getTodosFromStorage();
    todos.push(value);
    localStorage.setItem("todos",JSON.stringify(todos));
}
function showAlert(type, message){

    const alert = document.createElement("div");
    alert.className = `btn btn-${type}`
    alert.textContent = message;
    cardBody.appendChild(alert);
    setTimeout(() => {
        alert.remove();
    }, 1500); 
}
function addListItem(value){
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.className = "list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between";
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href ="#";
    a.className ="delete-item"; 
    a.innerHTML =" <i class = 'fa fa-remove'></i>";
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
    li.appendChild(a);
    list.appendChild(li);
    todoInput.value = "";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you find the correct item with `if(todo === deletetodo){`? You're calling `deleteTodosFromStorage(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.textContent);` but is that the correct value? Perhaps there is difference in whitespaces or something, so the `if` check never fires, so you never remove it from the array and this `localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));` just writes the same thing back to localStorage.

Comment: ```function deleteTodosFromStorage(deletetodo){
    let todos = getTodosFromStorage();
    console.log(deletetodo);
    todos.forEach(function(todo,index){
        if(todo === deletetodo){
            todos.splice(index,1);          
        }
    });
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
}
```
When i type console.log(deletetodo) in the function im getting the string value of the string value of the list item. so as you said if never fire but couldn't find the main problem